# Getting permission error accessing a rails application (apache + passenger)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I set up Apache + passenger for my Rails' application.
The following is apache's virtual host setting for the application:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName followbee.gvsumasl.com
   DocumentRoot /home/masler/followbeeportal/public/
   <Directory /home/masler/followbeeportal/public>
      AllowOverride all
      Options -MultiViews
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
      RailsEnv development
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is the permission settings for my application folder: (It's located in /home/masler)

```
drwxr-sr-x 13 root   www-data   4096 Mar 10 11:39 followbeeportal
```

The problem is that I can't access my website if I'm not logged in into my user account (masler) on the server (through ssh). If I ssh into my user account, I can access the website; otherwise, I'm getting a "Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server."

Do you have any idea what the problem could be? I'm using Ubuntu Server.